# Symfony2 - prod environment doesn't work (page 404)

Tags: php, symfony

I have problem with my Symfony2 project. I created new bundle using console, but default controller is avalible only from dev environment level.

For

`http://localhost/myproject/web/app_dev.php/hello/ZaqU`

everything works fine, but for

`http://localhost/myproject/web/app.php/hello/ZaqU`

i'm redirecting on

`http://localhost/myproject/web/hello/ZaqU`

and then i getting only page 404.
This is new bundle and i didn't changed default files so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Files:

```
/* @FILE: app/AppKernel.php */

$bundles = array(
   //...
    new ZaqU\TestBundle\ZaqUTestBundle(),
);
```

.

```
/* @FILE: app/config/routing.yml */
ZaqU_test:
    resource: "@ZaqUTestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might have not enabled the production environment in web/app.php. Change the false into true.

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: Whoever down voted this, any reason why is that? I mean isn't there any justification?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to clear your prod cache? Run the following command in the console:

```
./app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```